# How to change the theme name from default to whatever in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, themes

i'm new to laravel in my public/themes folder i have two themes named default and orange i want to go with orange but i can't see where the default keyword is specified. i'm trying to change this in ThemeviewFinder.php but it's only affecting the views not the assets. please help me

```
public function setActiveTheme($theme)
{

$users = DB::table('config')
                 ->select('activatedTheme')
                 ->where('id', 1)
                 ->get();
    //print_r($users);
    foreach($users as $row){
        $theme = $row->activatedTheme;

    }
   $this->activeTheme = $theme;
    array_unshift($this->paths, $this->basePath.'/'.$theme.'/views');
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything so far? The code you tried should appear in your question.

Comment: i have added@J. Chomel

Comment: Share a "global" variable in view with View::share('assets_path', app('assets_path')); containing the theme path, which you can declare in BaseContrlloer's __construct method.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to achieve this using a custom middleware. In my use-case, I was needing to display a different template/theme based on the domain name.

*TemplateMiddleware.php*

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $paths = [];
    $app = app();

    /*
     *  Pull our template from our site name
     */
    $template = Template::where('domain', Request::server('SERVER_NAME'))->first();
    if($template)
    {
        $paths = [
            $app['config']['view.paths.templates'] . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $template->tag
        ];
    }


    /*
     *  Default view path is ALWAYS last
     */
    $paths[] = $app['config']['view.paths.default'];

    /*
     * Overwrite the view finder paths
     */
    $finder = new FileViewFinder(app()['files'], $paths);
    View::setFinder($finder);

    return $next($request);
}
```

*Kernel.php*

```
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
    \App\Http\Middleware\TemplateMiddleware::class,
];
```